# Angular 4 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, angular, virtualbox

I guess I will start at the start of my application.

I am making a full mean-stack application and I want it to run in docker. To use docker I am using a virtualbox with Ubuntu. When I run my docker-compose, everything is working on localhost:4200. Now I want to open my application on my host machine (Windows 7).
When I go to my application via (ip addres should be kept secret, right?) xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:4200/login the page looks fine, but I get these errors: 
[image: Picture of console with errors]

I am using Angular cli 1.4.1 with node 8.4.0

Why am I getting these errors and how do I fix them?

My docker-compose

[image]

Comment: is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 127.0.0.1 ? it seems you are listening only on one single interface (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) and not 127.0.0.1. Your compose file would be helpful (especially the `ports` part.

Comment: @n00dl3 I added my compose file, and the ip is not 127.0.0.1

Comment: Is this running on your local machine ?

Comment: It is running in my virtual machine

Comment: then your app is not running on localhost, you should make your http call to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, not localhost. the js is interpreted inside your host, localhost for your host is its 127.0.0.1 IP, not xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx where your server runs.

Comment: In my browser I am making the call to xxx.xx... Where do I adjust it in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server which is listening on port `4200` is listening on your `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` interface (not necessary to hide lan IP, but nevermind...).

Your angular application is running on your host system. the localhost is the localhost of your host system, not the guest. so you have two solutions:

- changing your urls inside the angular application to point to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4200` instead of `localhost:4200`.
- Forwarding your 4200 port from your host to your guest system using virtual box :

  1. shutdown guest.
  2. select guest and click on `settings`
  3. go to the network tab.
  4. click on "advanced"
  5. then select "ports redirections" and bind your host 127.0.0.1:4200 to your guest's 4200 port